# Take a screenshot of more than one screen connected to the same device in rust language

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I got this code but it takes a screenshot of each screen separately, and I need to take the two screens together .

```
use screenshots::Screen;
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    let screens = Screen::all();
    unsafe {
        for screen in screens {
            let mut image = screen.capture().unwrap();
            let mut buffer = image.buffer();
            fs::write(format!("{}.png", screen.id.to_string()), &buffer).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7T1i.jpg)

Comment: You will probably need to assemble them somehow, which really depends on how the screens are oriented relative to the others.

Comment: Nitpick: There really isn't a reason to have an `unsafe` in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for this in `screenshots`.

You can, however, easily query the image coordinates from the `Screen` object and then combine it yourself:

```
use std::io::Cursor;

use image::{GenericImage, ImageFormat, RgbaImage};
use screenshots::Screen;

struct ScreenImage {
    screen: screenshots::Screen,
    image: screenshots::Image,
}

fn main() {
    // Capture all screens
    let screen_images = Screen::all()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|screen| {
            let image = screen.capture().unwrap();
            ScreenImage { screen, image }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    // Compute coordinates of combined image
    let x_min = screen_images.iter().map(|s| s.screen.x).min().unwrap();
    let y_min = screen_images.iter().map(|s| s.screen.y).min().unwrap();
    let x_max = screen_images
        .iter()
        .map(|s| s.screen.x + s.image.width() as i32)
        .max()
        .unwrap();
    let y_max = screen_images
        .iter()
        .map(|s| s.screen.y + s.image.height() as i32)
        .max()
        .unwrap();

    // Compute size and offset of combined image
    let offset = (x_min, y_min);
    let size = ((x_max - x_min) as u32, (y_max - y_min) as u32);
    println!("Total screenshot size: {:?}", size);
    println!("Offset: {:?}", offset);

    // Allocate combined image
    let mut img = RgbaImage::new(size.0, size.1);

    for screen_image in screen_images {
        let screenshot = image::io::Reader::new(Cursor::new(screen_image.image.buffer()))
            .with_guessed_format()
            .unwrap()
            .decode()
            .unwrap();
        img.copy_from(
            &screenshot,
            (screen_image.screen.x - offset.0) as u32,
            (screen_image.screen.y - offset.1) as u32,
        )
        .unwrap();
    }

    img.save_with_format("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat::Png)
        .unwrap();
}
```

I on purpose moved my screens in awkward positions to test the program. So I got:

```
Total screenshot size: (4480, 1846)
Offset: (-1920, 0)
```

[image: Screenshot Output]

Comment: https://ibb.co/5LybbX2
My friend, this is a picture of the code and it is working healthy, but when it is transferred from one project to another, the result is not satisfactory as shown in the second picture
https://ibb.co/TY2vY6B

Comment: Please try to solve this by yourself. Look at the return type of `Screen::all` at your old setup. Then look at the return type at your new setup. Look at the documentation of the `screenshot` crate und see if something changed between versions. If yes, adapt your code to the changes. You should learn how to solve these things by yourself, it will serve you well in the future.

Comment: I know that my friend, but I made sure that there is no change, but this is a mistake, that's why I turned to you

Comment: There is a change. I'm uncertain how you "made sure", but it didn't seem to have been very successful. v0.4 added an `Option` to the return value. So you need to write `Screen::all().unwrap()` now. You can even see in your screenshots that the annotations of the types changed.

Comment: Try to learn how to read the `docs.rs` page of a crate. It clearly states that it is [wrapped in an `Option`](https://docs.rs/screenshots/0.4.3/screenshots/struct.Screen.html#method.all) now. If you compare it [to the previous version](https://docs.rs/screenshots/0.3.3/screenshots/struct.Screen.html#method.all) you can see that there was no `Option` there before.

Comment: Also, compare the `Cargo.toml` files of your two setups, I'm pretty sure that one says `screenshot = 0.3` and the other one says `screenshot = 0.4`. According to semver rules, a major version change indicates that something in the API has changed incompatibly.

Comment: Thank you my friend, the solution has been completed, but it took a lot of effort, but I thank you with all my heart, you really helped me.